# Order from draft to confirmed by xmlrpc (Odoo 16)

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

Tips for confirming an order via php xmlrpc?

(draft to sale)

I use ripcord as library for xmlrpc and try:

```php
$r = $models->execute_kw(
    $db, $useruid, $password, 'sale.order', 'action_confirm',
    array(intval($order_id))
);
```

Edit: my fault method work

Comment: Are you getting an error when running your code? The `action_confirm` call would be most appropriate. You may want to try passing `$order_id` as an integer instead of an array.

Comment: With your suggestion I have:
"/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 59, in execute_kw return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {}) TypeError: Value after * must be an iterable, not int " }